# VS Code autocomplete for YAML/JSON config settings in Python files

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, autocomplete, yaml, pylance

In a Python project, I will soon be moving all my configuration parameters in a dedicated YAML file. Currently they are defined as variables in a separate Python file, which is probably bad practice but integrates very well with Pylance in VS Code, as it provides context-aware autocomplete and I can quickly navigate from the scripts to the config files.

Is there a way to set up something similar for YAML (or JSON) config files? Ideally, once the config is loaded as a Python dictionary, I would like to have autocomplete on the dictionary keys based on the YAML/JSON content, and ctrl+click on a key to navigate to the related config entry.

For instance, imagine I have a YAML file `config.yaml` like this:

```yaml
param1: value1
param2: value2
param3:
  param4: value4
  param5: value5
```

In a Python script that imports this config somehow (either as a dictionary of dictionaries, or any other format), I would like an autocomplete on the keys: e.g., if I type `config.para, I would like VS Code to propose autocompletes with param1, param2 or param3. And, ideally, I would like clicking on config.param1 to bring me to the corresponding entry in the YAML file.

I want to avoid defining a dataclass structure mirroring the content of the YAML files, which at this point is the only solution I can think of. I have looked into VS Code JSON/YAML schemas, but from what I understand it is not exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: You might be interested in typing.TypedDict or if you like working with classes, Pydantic. 
You can auto generate these schemas with tools such as https://json2pyi.pages.dev/

Comment: Not exactly ; JSON schemas allow for autocompletion when editing JSON scripts, but what I am looking for is autocompletion within Python scripts. I edited the question for clarity.